How to change a file in the gitlab ci pipeline before releasing the final archive?
We have a version.txt in our gitlab repository. During our pipeline we want to change the version number in that version.txt before the deploy step. When I change the value in the version.txt in a previous pipeline job, the changes won't be included in the release archive. I think gitlab just uses the current state from the last commit that triggered the pipeline. I tried to do a workaround with uploading the version.txt as an artifact and including it in the release step but the version.txt will just be outside the final archive.tar as an asset. But we want to have it inside the final .tar

Here my simplified code:
prepare_release:
  stage: prepare-deploy
  variables:
    VERSION_TAG: 1.0.0
  script:
  - echo "JOB_ID=$CI_JOB_ID" >> release.env
  - echo "VERSION_TAG=$VERSION_TAG" >> release.env 
  - echo "VERSION=$VERSION_TAG" > version.txt
  artifacts:
     paths:
       - version.txt
     reports:
       dotenv: release.env    

release:
  stage: deploy
  needs:
    - job: prepare_release
      artifacts: true
  script:
    - echo "Running release job..."
  release:
    name: Super Release
    tag_name: '$VERSION_TAG'
    assets:
      links:
        - name: 'version.txt'
          url: '$CI_SERVER_URL/$CI_PROJECT_PATH/-/jobs/$JOB_ID/artifacts/download'

